# Expressing $A \cup B \cup C$ as a union of mutually exclusive events

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A \cup B$ can be expressed as the union of two mutual exclusive events in the following way:

$$A \cup B = A \cup (B - AB)$$

Express $A \cup B \cup C$ in a similar way.

Comment: There's no question. **Edit:** I got it now. Please consider using punctuation. If you know how to make it work for $X\cup Y$, then just do it with $X=A$ and $Y=B\cup C$. You'll need to do this twice for different $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @GitGud, he's asking how to write $A \cup B \cup C$ as a disjoint union.

Comment: @user18921 Yes, I think so too. Finally got it.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please take careful note of the edits I made to your question. For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex). Also, in future questions, please use proper punctuation to the best of your ability.

Comment: If you draw a Venn diagram, it will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

$$A \cup B \cup C = A \cup (A^c \cap B) \cup (A^c \cap B^c \cap C).$$

The intuition is as follows. The first term (namely $A$), gets us all the elements of $A$. The second term (namely $A^c \cap B$) gets us all the elements in $B$, but leaves out those that we already got with our first term. Etc.

Try writing the pattern out for the $n=4$ case.